# Show that $z = e^y f\left(ye^{\frac{x^2}{2y^2}}\right)$ satisfies $(x^2-y^2)\frac{\partial z}{\partial x} + xy\frac{\partial z}{\partial y} = xyz$

Tags: multivariable-calculus

Show that $z = e^y f\left(ye^{\frac{x^2}{2y^2}}\right)$ satisfies

$$(x^2-y^2)\frac{\partial z}{\partial x} + xy\frac{\partial z}{\partial y} = xyz$$

I am trying to find the partials. Do I treat $f$ as a function $x$ and $y$? Or is $z$ just a function of $y$ and $f$ so:

$$\frac{\partial z}{\partial x} = \frac{\partial z}{\partial f} \frac{\partial f}{\partial x} =e^y f'\left(ye^{\frac{x^2}{2y^2}}\right) y\frac{2x}{2y^2} e^{\frac{x^2}{2y^2}} = e^y f'\left(ye^{\frac{x^2}{2y^2}}\right) \frac{x}{y} e^{\frac{x^2}{2y^2}}$$

I am not sure how exactly to treat this function.

Comment: No, $f$ is a function of a single variable, say $u$. PLEASE do not write $\partial z/\partial f$. This makes absolutely no sense. You need to use the product rule (and *then* the chain rule) to compute $\partial z/\partial x$ and $\partial z/\partial y$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since $z = e^y f(y e^{x^2/(2y^2)})$, we can simply substitute that expression in for $z$:
$$
(x^2 - y^2) \frac{\partial}{\partial x} \left[e^y f\left(y e^{\frac{x^2}{2y^2}}\right)\right] + x y  \frac{\partial}{\partial y} \left[e^y f\left(y e^{\frac{x^2}{2y^2}}\right) \right] = xye^y f\left(y e^{\frac{x^2}{2y^2}}\right)
$$
Then you evaluate the derivatives in the left-hand side and see if it ends up equal to the right-hand side. You'll need to use the product rule and the chain rule to do so.